# Cannot use TabView on SwiftUI, WatchOS

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, watchos-6

Is there a way to use TabView using SwiftUI on WatchOS?

I've seen most of the WWDC talks and they don't mention it for WatchOS. Moreover, in the apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview) it is not enumerated under SDK's.

Whenever I try to add it to a WatchOS project I get the following error:

`'TabView' is unavailable in watchOS`

Or is there a good way to replicate the desired TabView ?

I want something similar to this:
[image]
Two different pages that are changed simply by swiping horizontally.

Comment: It seems like you found your answer. TabView is not available on the watch.

Comment: Amazing answer!

Comment: Why do you want a TabView in WatchOS?

Comment: I want to create a UI similar to [this](https://www.gihosoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/accurate-weather-app-for-apple-watch-accuweather.png)

Comment: You can write it yourself. It is just an HStack containing 3 Buttons. Each button contains a VStack with an Image and Label inside

Answer (score 5):

If you want a page based navigation (swipe left/right between view controllers) in your app you simply add another WKHostingController to your project's storyboard. Connect the two hosting controllers by creating a segue between them. The segue is what determines how you navigate between controllers.

This page has a good guide on how to do it: https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_WatchKit_Page-based_Navigation_Tutorial

Just keep in mind that you want to add another hosting controller to the storyboard, not anything else.

I have not found a way to do this programmatically in SwiftUI, this seems like the only way to do it for now.

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I have a few issues though. [1] When I added the the new WKHostingController I had to assign it a new `HostingController2.swift` file and inside of that a new View that will be initialized to that `WKHostingController`. This means that the main entry point controller has its own hosting controller which then has its own view (Content view). The same goes for the second `WKHostingController ` The thing is that I'm using an Observable object to be my 'source of truth.' How can I use the same Observable object  (EnvironmentObject) in both `Content()` and `Content2()` ?

Comment: The [2] issue is that initially I want to start with one view. Then lets say click a button and now have 3 `WKHostingController`, any possible way to do that ?

Comment: I was able to solve the first problem implementing something like [this](https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/467). I'm having issues with the 2nd issue I have 3 Hosting Controllers ( HC1, HC2, HC3) HC1 is the initial controller and it has a `NavigationLink` to HC2 using `NavigationLink(destinationName: "HC2")` In the `storyboard` I have that  HC2 has "Relationship 'next page' to HC3" (segue) The issue is that the NavLink does take us to HC2 but from there I cannot reach HC3. Meaning that I do not see the dot and am not able to swipe to the next page (HC3). Any ideas of what's happening ?

Comment: If you use WKHostingController's `.presentController(withNameAndContexts:)` or `reloadRootControllers(withNamesAndContexts:)` you can load a new WKHostingController set that will be shown as pages

Answer (score 5):

It's now available starting with watchOS 7: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview.