# How to style rows in SwiftUI List on WatchOS?

Tags: watchkit, swiftui, apple-watch

I'm working with SwiftUI and is trying to make a list of buttons with custom .buttonStyle inside a List view on WatchOS, but can't get it to work. Is this even currently possible, and if so, how?

Example project:

```
struct Superhero: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

var superheroes = [
    Superhero(name: "Batman"),
    Superhero(name: "Superman"),
    Superhero(name: "Wonder Woman"),
    Superhero(name: "Aquaman"),
    Superhero(name: "Green Lantern"),
    Superhero(name: "The Flash")
]

struct SuperheroButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

  func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.white.opacity(0.95) : .green)
        .cornerRadius(13.0)
  }
}

struct SuperHeroesView: View{
    var body: some View {
        List {

            ForEach(superheroes) { superhero in
                Button(action: {
                    print(superhero.name)
                }){
                    Text(superhero.name)
                }.buttonStyle(SuperheroButtonStyle())
           }

       }
    }
}
```

This code produces this:
[image: picture of WatchOS app]

Instead, I want the buttons to look more like this:

[image: picture of wanted result]

In this last example, I'm using ScrollView instead of List which means I'm not getting the nice animation of rows shrinking and fading away when scrolling through the list.

I've tried playing with negative padding, but that can't give me a bigger corner radius (more round corners than the default) and doesn't really look like good.

So is there a way to apply a ButtonStyle on items in a List view correctly, including having a custom cornerRadius?

Or is there some other way of getting more control of the way the rows look while still keeping the animation that comes with List?

Comment: I'd also like to know if there is a way to do this properly!

Comment: I’ve been trying to do this too. There is a property you can add on a list called `listStyle` I haven’t been able to get it to work. Moreover, I’ve been trying to implement what you did (two views with the dot marker is the bottom) Can you perhaps [help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58036807/cannot-use-tabview-on-swiftui-watchos?noredirect=1#comment102477434_58036807)

Comment: Rather than post an answer that might miss the point, have you looked at applying `.listStyle(CarouselListStyle())` to your `List`?

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if you've figured this out yet or not, but I ended up using

```
List {

        ForEach(superheroes) { superhero in
            Button(action: {
                print(superhero.name)
            }){
                Text(superhero.name)
            }
            .buttonStyle(SuperheroButtonStyle())
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
       }

   }
```

to extend the edges of my buttons to the edge of the list like this:

[image: Rows with extended edges]

You can also add the modifier

```
.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 20)
```

to the List itself to allow the rows height to scale down to the size you want. I chose 20 for this example:

[image: Correctly sized row height]

And finally there's a

```
.listRowPlatterColor(.clear)
```

modifier you can use to change the background color of the row itself. I chose clear for this example to hide the edges that aren't fully covered by the button.

[image: Clear Platter]

Comment: I still have this tiny bit of gray from the default styling of the button left over on WatchOS. Driving me nuts! But thank you for this, it did help.

Comment: Important: this only works if you didn't initialize a list with `init(content:)`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58210994/3151675

Answer (score 7):

[.listRowPlatterColor(.clear)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3278590-listrowplattercolor) Gave me what I was looking for. That was probably harder than it needed to be to find that.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var EnrouteText = "Enroute"
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                self.EnrouteText = getCurrentTime()
            }) {
                Text(EnrouteText)
            }
            .buttonStyle(BtnStyle(bgColor: .red, fgColor: .white))
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            .listRowPlatterColor(.clear)

            // The rest of the buttons.
        }
    }
}

// Button Styles
struct BtnStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var bgColor: Color
    var fgColor: Color

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(fgColor)
            .background(bgColor)
            .cornerRadius(32)
    }
}
```

[image: Example of using listRowPlatterColor to clear the final part of the background]

Comment: `listRowPlatterColor(_:)` is deprecated. For watchOS 7.0+ [use listItemTint(_:)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71911326/145173).

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/elements/buttons/), it's recommended that buttons within a scrolling view (e.g. `List`) look like a rounded rectangle (rather than a capsule).

If you attempt to use `.listRowBackground`, you'll get a sharp rectangle (not desired):

> [image]

If you instead use `.listRowPlatterColor`, you'll get exactly what Apple recommends you use (in one line of code, nonetheless):

> [image]

```
Button("Log out") {}
  .listRowPlatterColor(Color.blue)
```

Comment: `listRowPlatterColor(_:)` is deprecated. For watchOS 7.0+ [use listItemTint(_:)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71911326/145173).

Answer (score 2):

To have a the background of the whole cell in a certain colour you have to use `.listRowBackground`  modifier. You can either use a `Capsule` or a `RoundedRectangle` as the background depending on your preference:

```
struct SuperHeroesView: View{
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(superheroes) { superhero in
                Button(action: { print(superhero.name) }){
                    Text(superhero.name)
                }   .buttonStyle(SuperheroButtonStyle())
            }   .listRowBackground(Capsule()
                                       .fill(Color.green))
                // or as an alternative:
                //.listRowBackground(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13.0)
                //                       .fill(Color.green))
       }
    }
}
```

You would also probably want to change the button style, as the background highlight effect will only affect the button, not the whole cell:

```
struct SuperheroButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

  func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? .gray : .white)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [listItemTint(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/listitemtint(_:)-29jxa). Also, consider preferring an [adaptive corner radius](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/elements/buttons/) per the Human Interface Guidelines over a hard-coded value from a custom style.

```swift
List(superheroes) { superhero in
    Button(superhero.name) { /* take action */ }
        .listItemTint(.accentColor)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct SuperHeroesView: View{
        var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(superheroes) { superhero in
                    Button(action: {
                        print(superhero.name)
                    }){
                        Text(superhero.name)
                    }.buttonStyle(SuperheroButtonStyle())
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 20)

            }
        }
    }
```