# Is page-based navigation possible in a SwiftUI app on WatchOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I see page-based navigation is [supported](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/app-architecture/navigation/) for WatchOS, but is there a way to access this functionality with SwiftUI?

[image: page-based-navigation]

Comment: I posted a detailed description how to implement this as an answer to another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62392066/1687087

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using the new SwiftUI App Lifecycle and can't access Storyboards (or just need a solution for App Delegate Cycle without using Storyboards), you can use the new Page View style in SwiftUI 2:

```
WindowGroup {
   TabView {
     Page1View()
     Page2View()
   }
   .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
}
```

Comment: Yes TabView does it, new for WatchOS 7.  This allowed me to finally delete the storyboard entirely. Thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed more than 10 pages?

Comment: @alamodey seems like there's a limitation of 10 items. I am unable to add more. But for the main page based navigation, you wouldn't want more than 10 tabs would you? :)

Comment: @SharathSriram I used this UI element to create a series of tips to use my Watch app so I had a bit more than 10 but trimmed it down to 10 now.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible. First, define hosting controllers for each of your pages like so

```
class Page1HostingController: WKHostingController<Page1View> {
    override var body: Page1View {
        self.setTitle("page1")
        return Page1View()
    }
}

class Page2HostingController: WKHostingController<Page2View> {
    override var body: Page2View {
        self.setTitle("page2")
        return Page2View()
    }
}
```

where `Page1View` and `Page2View` are your SwiftUI implementations.

Then, add new view controllers to your `Interface.storyboard`, set their implementation classes to your new controller classes and connect them via a "next page" segue.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  I thought SwiftUI was supposed to do away with the story boards though.

Answer (score -1):

There is [NavigationLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) button which triggers a navigation presentation when pressed.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack() {
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination view"), label: {
        Text("Title of the NavigationLink button")
      })
    }
  }
```