# How can I make a storyboard to the left of an initial view storyboard on Apple Watch using SwiftuI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch

My Goal:
To make 3 views side by side, where each view takes up all of the Apple Watches viewable area.  Something like Apple's workout app when it's on a current workout.

Using the stack overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331552/implementing-page-based-navigation-for-swiftui-apple-watch-app/62392066?noredirect=1#comment112174864_62392066) I figured out how to use storyboards to make swipable views to the *right* of the Initial view, but how can I make a swipable view to the *left* of the initial storyboard view?

When I connect views with `ctrl` mouse from one view to another, the only segue option I get is `next page`, which makes a swipable view to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in SwiftUI 2.0 it looks like there is a very easy way to integrate this with a simple `TabView` and I'll show an example

```swift
struct threeViewsInOne{
    
    @State private var selectedPage = 1
    
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedPage) {
            ViewA.tag(0)
            ViewB.tag(1)
            ViewC.tag(2)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
}
```